# Problems connecting to Postgresql server?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am running a Postgresql server hosted on heroku as part of an app I am developing.  I've been using PGAdmin as a frontend to set up my tables and also check to make sure the app is correctly writing data to the tables.  When I am at home it connects fine and I can use it with no problems.  It also works when I tether to my phone's WiFi hotspot.  However when I am in university on the WiFi it does not connect.  I get the following error:

```
"could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server 
running on host <MY HOSTNAME> and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"
```

I'm trying to troubleshoot this.  I tried the obvious things like checking my hostname and port are correct (they are, because it works from home!) and checking that Pgadmin has permissions in windows firewall (it does).  Not sure what to try next.

Is it likely to be that the port is blocked?  I used an online port checker which reported that the port (5432) was closed, however it also says this when using my phone's wifi hotspot (which normally works, as I said).  Is there another port I can use with Postgresql?

Comment: Could it be the listen address in the postgres.conf file, usually in the installed data directory.

Comment: @Mokadillion - I will try that.  If the listen address was wrong though, wouldn't that mean I couldn't even connect from home?

Comment: @Mokadillion I can't find the data directory - where is it normally found?

Comment: once connected you can execute the query "show data_directory" this will tell you where it is. It may also be the pg_hba.conf file. this will tell you the users that have access and the source ip addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it turns out the port 5432 was actually closed on my university's WiFi.  I was able to request that it be opened, and everything is now working.